# How to have multiple dynamic jQuery progress bars

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, progress-bar

I am trying to have multiple progress bars animate at the same time, but to different values. Using the following HTML and jQuery both bars go to the same end value.

```
<progress id="progressbar" value="50" max="100"></progress><span class="progress-value">0%</span>
<progress id="progressbar" value="30" max="100"></progress><span class="progress-value">0%</span>
```

......

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

var progressbar = $('#progressbar'),  
        max = progressbar.attr('value'),  
        time = (1000/max)*2,      
        value = 0 

    var loading = function() {  
        value += 1;  
        addValue = progressbar.val(value);  

        $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');  

        if (value == max) {  
            clearInterval(animate);                      
        }  
    };  

    var animate = setInterval(function() {  
        loading();  
    }, time);  

});
</script>
```

I know that this is because both instances of the progressbar are just following the same jQuery, but I have no idea how to make it dynamic. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
var progressbar2 = $('#progressbar2'),  
max2 = progressbar2.attr('value'),  
time2 = (1000/max2)*2,      
    value2 = 0 

    var loading2 = function() {  
    value2 += 1;  
    addValue = progressbar2.val(value); 

    $('.progress-value2').html(value + '%');  

    if (value2 == max2) {  
        clearInterval(animate2);                      
    }  
}; 
var animate2 = setInterval(function() {  
    loading2();  
}, time);
```

This works (adding a clone of the original function), but obviously it's not something I want to do. Is there a way I could iterate through all of the possible progress bars I'll have, using something similar to a for loop?

Comment: IDs have to be unique, you can't have two `id="progressbar"`.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that was where the problem was coming from I just didn't know how to address it in jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You should give each control a different id , e.g. progressbar1 , progressbar2 etc..
You can use class selector instead of id selector, 
then iterate over each element with the "progress-value" class.
like so:

```
$('.progress-value').each(function(i, obj) {
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am EXTREMELY new to jQuery though so I need to ask a bit more. I've placed my entire code inside the class selector function you provided, but now I don't know how to select the specific progressbar ids. I'm trying something like `var progressbar = $('#progressbar'+i), ` but obviously that isn't working.

Comment: Just added an edit, please look at it and tell me if I could make it better.

Comment: `$('.progress-value').each(function(i) {
  var barID = '#progressbar'+i,
      progressbar = $(barID)
      max = progressbar.attr('value'),  
          time = (1000/max)*2,      
         value = 0
        var loading = function() 
        {  
         value += 1;  
         addValue = progressbar.val(value); 
         $('.progress-value').html(value + '%');  
         if (value == max) 
         {  
             clearInterval(animate);                      
         }  
     };  
     var animate = setInterval(function() {  
      loading();}, time); });` Tried that, stuck in infinite loop.